# Windows XP - non-user input data filter message after installing wireless keyboard & mouse

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-keyboard

After I installed  MS wireless keyboard and mouse and associated software, I started getting this annoying  message  titled "Hardware installation" telling me the software I am trying to install did not pass the XP logo tests.

The software is for "HID non-user input data filter" and I have two options  Continue anyway or stop installation. Now, if I try to continue the installation fails, if  stop installing another message pops up with a little mouse logo and the whole process repeats itself.
after I am done with that message a third dialog appears.

This is happening every time I boot up my PC (a desktop),  I tried following an advice I found in some forum and download windows update for ID non-user input data filter, but that installation failed as well.

The thing is, that both  keyboard and mouse are working fine

Is there anyway to get past these dialogs ?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the driver signing warnings easily:

- Right-click My Computer and select **Properties**
- On the  **Hardware** tab, click **Driver Signing** under **Drivers**
- Select **Ignore – Install the software anyway and don’t ask for my approval** then hit OK

[image]

Comment: that will take care of the warning alright (funny that even MS' very own drivers fail the test :), the real issue, however, seems to be: why has the driver to be installed at each boot?

Comment: Well his ultimate question was "is there anyway to get past these dialogs ?". I think it's been addressed. For whatever reason, XP may not see that he already installed driver software, and then it tries to install it's own.